# Implementing Zip Reader

Tags: android, filereader, zip

Well I have been searching on how to do it, but I haven't found nothing to guide me in. How can this be done? I'm not asking you to make the code for me, just tell me where to start.

Comment: First hit from Google: http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8362

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ZipInnputStream .. [see reference here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)